# Problem while navigating to cross origin URL in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Is there any way to navigate to cross origin URL from a React.js App?

`window.location.href = **cross origin url**`

This only works at first try then it doesn't as the app is saved as PWA. It just redirects to the same origin due to caching.

Comment: try window.location.replace() [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

Comment: it's the problem with serviceworker... by default it caches the server@YosiLeibman

Comment: for example i have "test.com" as my main url... and "test.com/api/facebook" is the url API url... but service worker caches the /api/facebook and only returns homepage... so i want to prevent the caching in certain url matches in serviceworker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've solved it by adding the code snippet below inside `serviceWorker.js`

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
   // ...

   if (isAPIRoute()) {
        console.info("unregistering service worker for api route");
        unregister();
        console.info("reloading");
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
   } 

   // ...
}

function isAPIRoute() {
  return window.location.pathname.startsWith("/api");
}
```

Comment: This works for me as well. The service worker cached some of my api routing.
My problem was the URL having a query https://www.example.com/api/consent?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F1234   and service worker cached the URL. 
However, the service worker does not cache https://www.example.com/api/consent?redirect_uri=http://Fwww.example.com%2F1234 , I still have no idea how the service worker consider to cache the API route.